# Como fazer uma alteração em "Cascata" utilizando oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

Como eu posso alterar o ID da minha table BANDAS_E_ARTISTAS e garantir que nas outras tabelas estrangeiras mudem também via PL/SQL?

```
TABLE BANDAS_E_ARTISTAS

ID NOME_ARTISTICO
01 RAÇA NEGRA
02 OS MENUDOS
03 KELLY KEY
04 LUIZ CARLOS
--------------------------

TABLE ARTISTA

ID NOME_REAL
03 KELLY JOANA
04 LUIZ CARLOS
--------------------------

TABLE BANDA

ID ESTILO
01 PAGODE
02 ROCK
--------------------------

TABLE ARTISTA_EM_BANDA

ID_BANDA ID_ARTISTA
01       04

--------------------------
```

A table **BANDAS_E_ARTISTAS** guardo o ID(chave primária) de toda a identificação das outras tabelas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer isso automaticamente não há como. Você deverá criar uma procedure que receba a nova PK e atualize automaticamente em todas as tabelas referenciadas.

Esse procedure deverá fazer:

1. Criar uma nova linha pai com o novo valor de chave
2. atualizar todas as linhas na tabela subordinada que apontam para a antiga linha principal para apontar para a nova linha principal
3. Excluir a antiga linha pai
4. comitar

Mas, se você desejar, existe uma biblioteca externa criada por um programador que faz esse processo automaticamente.

Como instalar se encontra [nesse link](http://tkyte.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html)

Como utilizar:

No SQLPlus do oracle, conectado ao banco criado, execute o seguinte comando para cada tabela que será feito a atualização da PK :

```
Exec update_cascade.on_table(‘Nome da Tabela’);
```

Execute o comando de atualização dos registros que deseja atualizar:

```
UPDATE TABLE_X SET PRIMARYKEY_X = 1000 WHERE PRIMARYKEY_X = 10;
```

O resultado será que onde o sistema encontrar a PK_X = 10 , a trigger trocará nas tabelas filhas onde o valor for igual a 10 por 1000, sem precisar desabilitar constraint do banco de dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Utilize-se no seu POST para falar com os usuários. Qualquer pergunta do motivo, utilize @ + o Nome do Usuário. Poderá ver que nos comentários seu próprio post é possível realizar a pergunta diretamente a mim. Obrigado

Comment: Desculpe, eu não tinha visto que você já tinha comentado na pergunta. Obrigado por me alertar.